# ContainerView with shadow and rounded edges

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uicontainerview, dropshadow

I would like to create custom ContainerView with shadowed and rounded edges. This ContainerView is in form of small rectangle placed on the top of another UIView. In this peculiar situation neither additional layers nor drawing shadow using CoreGraphics are helpful.

[image]

Comment: Why do you think that additional view's/layers won't help? Is your problem that you don't see the shadow after applying `cornerRadius` to `containerView`?

Comment: Every time I apply additional views/layers shadow is visible and edges are rounded, but I cannot get rid off this "white" area.

Comment: You should post your code in order to get help with that.

Comment: Have you tried setting `containerView.layer.masksToBounds = true`?

Answer (score 5):

You're wrong that additional views/layers won't help.

You can place `roundedContainer` with rounded corners into another `shadowedView` with shadow added to it's layer.
To avoid those white corners make sure you set background color to `clear` somewhere.

Example:

```
//superview for container with rounded corners
shadowedView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear //this will fix your white corners issue
shadowedView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
shadowedView.layer.shadowOffset = .zero
shadowedView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3
shadowedView.layer.shadowRadius = 5.0

//add a container with rounded corners
let roundedView = UIView()
roundedView.frame = baseView.bounds
roundedView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
roundedView.layer.masksToBounds = true
shadowedView.addSubview(roundedView)
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a proper solution. I dropped shadow to `ContainerView` which is a superclass for every `UIView` inside. Then, I rounded edges using `UIViewController` class for this small rectangle area.

```
class GraphViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var graphView: GraphViewRenderer!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        graphView.layer.cornerRadius = 20.0
        graphView.layer.masksToBounds = true

        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}

class GraphContainerView: UIView {
    func applyPlainShadow() {
        layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.zero
        layer.shadowRadius = 5.0
        layer.shadowOpacity = 0.7
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        applyPlainShadow()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        applyPlainShadow()
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not a super class, it's a superview. That's not the same. Your answer is basically what I was suggesting.

Comment: Thanks @alexburtnik for help.